# Data is being saved in SQL DB as 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and like any other language working with the date/time is a pain. I've an HTML form in which I've fields that when loads look like this:

[image]

The code behind the last two fields i.e. Date Joined and Last Changed is:

```
<input class="form-control-sm w-100" id="date_joined" value="@(Employee.DateJoined == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.UtcNow : Employee.DateJoined)" autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control-sm w-100" id="last_changed" value="@DateTime.Now" readonly="readonly" />
```

As you can see the Last Changed field is readonly but user can change the date in Date Joined field. Now when the save button is clicked the value of Date Joined is saved successfully but the value of Last Changed is saved as `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`. Here is the controller code of what happens when save button is clicked:

```
public IActionResult SaveEmployee(Employee employee) {
            try
            {
                _db.Employees.Add(employee);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error while saving" });
            }
}
```

Now the data of employee is coming from type script:

```
   private save() {
        try {
            const employee = this.createEmployee();

            Util.request(this.urlSaveEmployee, 'post', 'json', (response) => {
                if (response != null) {
                    $.notify(response.message);
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $.notify(response.message);
                    console.error('Failed to get data #T7G985. Please try again.');
                }
            }, () => { }, employee);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    private createEmployee() {
        try {

            const employee = {
                Firstname: $('#first_name').val(),
                Lastname: $('#last_name').val(),
                Position: $('#position').val(),
                Department: $('#department').val(),
                Salary: $('#salary').val(),
                DateJoined: $('#date_joined').val(),
                LastChanged: $('#last_changed').val()
            };

            return employee;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Any idea why it is still saving the date in min value of DateTime?**

---

**UPDATE**

Through a breakpoint I can see that the typescript is returning the correct value.
[image]

Also when `employee` is passed to controllder from type script this is where it is showing the date wrong.

[image]

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint on the `SaveEmployee` method to check if the date is correct there? The problem may not lie with the DB at all

Comment: just a thought, shouldn't `LastChanged` date be set on the server side, and not come from the client?

Comment: @MindSwipe I've placed a break point just before the `return employee;` and printed the `console.log(employee)` and both the values are correct but then when it goes to controller which saves it in the database, for some reason it didn't save the Last hanged date correctly but it stores Date Joined correctly..

Comment: And you are sure that this is a DB problem? Not some weird JSON issue? Can I ask you again if you checked server side in the `SaveEmployee` method, and if the date/ time properties of the employee object are correct?

Comment: @MindSwipe l'm new to ASP.NET let me make sure I understand the question correctly. So I'm using SQL DB locally which I created using `add-migration` & then `update-database`. I'm not sure what do you mean by server side `SaveEmployee` method as per my understanding everything is happening in typescript and controller for saving in local SQL DB.

Comment: if the field is readonly in the UI, i.e. generated by the application, you should not rely on the UI value, but on the generated value.

Comment: That's not quite correct. The C# code you are writing runs on the server and is not coupled to your Type/JavaScript frontend code. In between the two they need to share information, and this is typically done over HTTP requests containing JSON information. And you *cannot* debug your backend (server side C#) with the browser, the browser only knows about the frontend. To debug the backend you'll need to attach the debugger to your asp.net process. This done the easiest using Visual Studio and launching the project in Debug mode from it, or using the VS Code C# Extension

Comment: @devio can you post a code example? As I'm learning ASP.NET and not quite sure how to do it exactly.

Comment: @MindSwipe so in the "CreateEmployee" method which is basically in controller file i.e. `public IActionResult SaveEmployee(Employee employee)` I'm printing the `employee` values here and here the value of `Last Changed` becomes `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` for some reason.

Comment: I don't know if it does. That's what I'm asking you. I'm saying it *could* be that somewhere in transit from JS to JSON to C# the values could be mangled. But I can't know or check that, you need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model `Employee` has property as `LastUpdated` and your are passing `LastChanged` from the `javascript`.

Update `post` object property `LastChanged` to `LastUpdated` then it will work.

Your `createEmployee()` will updated like below.

```
private createEmployee() {
    try {

        const employee = {
            Firstname: $('#first_name').val(),
            Lastname: $('#last_name').val(),
            Position: $('#position').val(),
            Department: $('#department').val(),
            Salary: $('#salary').val(),
            DateJoined: $('#date_joined').val(),
            LastUpdated: $('#last_changed').val()  // Updated property name
        };

        return employee;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You :D That's my number 1 mistake as I'm learning .NET...

Comment: This is the first thing we should check. Even sometimes simple typo can cause so much trouble. Sometimes we write `LastUpdated` and we are mistype it to `LastUpdetad`. Initially it would look the same but if we focus on spelling correctly we find the issue. :-)

Comment: Hey do check this out if you can answer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279687/buttons-in-tr-not-working-after-search-is-finished-asp-net-core-3-1