# Buttons in <tr> not working after search is finished ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core

I've just implemented search in a sample web app that I'm working on. Search works fine and here is how I've done that:

**Typecript Search function**

```
    private search(keyword) {
        try {
            if (keyword === '' || keyword === undefined) {
                $('employees_list tbody').empty();
            } else { const data = { keyword: keyword };

                Util.request(this.urlSearchEmployee, 'GET', 'html', (response) => {
                    const currentKeyWord = $('#keyword').val();
                    if (currentKeyWord === keyword) {
                        $('#employees_list tbody').empty();
                        $('#employees_list tbody').append(response);
                    }
                }, function () {
                        $.notify('Failed to get data. Please try again.');
                        console.error('Failed to get data #T09576. Please try again.');
                }, data);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
```

**Search function in controller**

```
                var employees = await _db.Employees.Where(e => 
                e.LastName.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()) ||
                e.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()) ||
                e.Position.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower())
                ).ToListAsync();

                //Console.WriteLine(employees);
                ViewData["EmployeesList"] = employees;
                return PartialView("~/Views/Employee/_TableData.cshtml");
```

**Table View file**

```
@{
    List<Employee> EmployeeList = (List<Employee>)ViewData["EmployeesList"];
}

@if (EmployeeList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var employee in EmployeeList)
    {
        <tr class="employees-row" style="width: 20%; text-align:center;">
            <td>@employee.FirstName</td>
            <td>@employee.LastName</td>
            <td>@employee.Position</td>
            <td>@employee.Department</td>
            <td>@employee.Salary</td>
            <td>@employee.DateJoined</td>
            <td>@employee.LastUpdated</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark employee-edit" data-id="@employee.EmployeeId">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger employee-delete" data-id="@employee.EmployeeId">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

The search works fine. But when the search result is loaded there are two buttons to edit or delete. And when I click these buttons they don't do anything. The same buttons work when the table rows are normal meaning when table rows are not search results.

**Update**
Here is the delete button click events:
 **Typescript:**

```
                $('.employee-delete').click((e) => {
                    alert("Delete Button Clicked");
                    const id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
                    const data = {
                        id: id
                    };

                    this.delete(data);
                });
```

Then the `delete()` method in typscript:

```
    private delete(data) {
        try {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this employee?") == true) {

                Util.request(this.urlDeleteEmployee, 'post', 'json', () => {
                    $.notify(`Employee deleted successfully.`);
                    location.reload();
                }, () => {
                    $.notify(`Failed to delete Employee. Please try again`);
                }, data);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
```

This after search result the delete button nor edit button doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: Where is button click events? There should be some javascript code which has assigned click events to your button.

Comment: @Karan just updated.

Comment: `location.reload();` after this runs what do you expect?

Comment: show your table element setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be when you search the table, it will rebinding the DOM. So your previous click bindings of buttons will be vanished.

So rather than using `$('.employee-delete').click(...)` use `delegate` type `bindings` with `$(document).on("click", ".employee-delete", (e) => { ... }`.

It will assigned to dynamically created objects also. Update it like below.

```
$(document).on("click", ".employee-delete", (e) => {

   const id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
   const data = { id: id };
   this.delete(data);

});
```

Comment: Thank you once again for helping me out. :)